# Editing HTML & CSS file content with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am working on a web app that allows user to edit specific HTML & CSS elements.
For example, the user can specify the label of an anchor tag and where it links to, or specify the background color of the page using a form.

To create the initial file, i was thinking of using some kind of templating engine, where i can replace the value of a specific tag, but im not to sure on how to retrieve the existing values from a file that was created before. The workaround i can think of is using regex to search through the entire file and get the values that matches some certain pattern, but is there any easier way to do this?

update:
here is an example:

```
<a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$link_label?></a>
```

i want to be able to replace those links, and save the result in a file, and later on, i want to be able to retrieve the values that replaced these variables/

Comment: do you have any examples of code?

Comment: an action on your view(changing a color or a label) should not update the view directly, but an underlying model that will hold all the variables and rerender your view according its state. that way you can save the model , and rerender it later.

Comment: camus, im not updating the view, im trying to create a kind of a CMS-ish application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is cascading. So you can allow the user to define their own CSS which is then included after the default CSS is. However, this is not safe- phishing, clickjacking, etc. The better would be that you define the attributes they can define (thus filter and validate it), store it in a database table (or XML/JSON file), query the table, generate CSS from result and include it after the default CSS.

In regards to HTML specific items; PHP is dynamic; you can store the user's preferences in a database table (like MySQL) and query for these upon generating the page. I wouldn't go about creating individual user specific files, it would defeat the purpose of PHP.

Comment: the user dont define their own CSS, its like im providing them with some templates, and they can edit some values in it with a webform.

Comment: Yeah. The user fills in the form with their custom values, you store these values in your database (or whatever storage you wish) and then use these values to generate their dynamic page.

Comment: Oh, so, you meant like create a create a db to store the editable 'fields' for each HTML and CSS files?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the ways. You can also look into client side storage (cookies or HTML5 web storage) thus avoiding the need for the database completely and producing a more scalable solution.

Comment: seems like thats the only way for now.. will keep looking for ways, thanks for the suggestion anyway...